# Disable property mutation in JS

Tags: javascript, abstraction

I was creating a component and was trying to break my implementation. The idea is to not allow user to manipulate the exposed properties.

The implementation was like this:

```js
function MyClass(){
  var data = [];
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'data', {
    get: function(){ return data; },
    set: function(){ throw new Error('This operation is not allowed'); },
    configurable: false,
  });
}

var obj = new MyClass();

try {
  obj.data = [];
} catch(ex) {
  console.log('mutation handled');
}

obj.data.push('Found a way to mutate');

console.log(obj.data)
```

As you see, setting the property is handled but user is still able to mutate it using `.push`. This is because I'm returning a reference.

I have handled this case like:

```js
function MyClass(){
  var data = [];
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'data', {
    get: function(){ return data.slice(); },
    set: function(){ throw new Error('This operation is not allowed'); },
    configurable: false,
  });
}

var obj = new MyClass();

try {
  obj.data = [];
} catch(ex) {
  console.log('mutation handled');
}

obj.data.push('Found a way to mutate');

console.log(obj.data)
```

As you see, I'm returning a new array to solve this. Not sure how it will affect performance wise.

**Question:** Is there an alternate way to not allow user to mutate properties that are of type *object*?

I have tried using `writable: false`, but it gives me error when I use it with `get`.

---

**Note:** I want this array to mutable within class but not from outside.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you are effectively blocking attempts to modify `MyClass`. However, other objects members of `MyClass` are still JavaScript objects. That way you're doing it (returning a new Array for every call to `get`) is one of the best ways, though of course, depending of how frequently you call `get` or the length of the array might have performance drawbacks.

Of course, if you could use ES6, you could extend the native Array to create a `ReadOnlyArray` class. You can actually do this in ES5, too, but you lose the ability to use square brackets to retrieve the value from a specific index in the array.

Another option, if you can avoid Internet Explorer, is to use `Proxies` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

With a proxy, you can trap calls to get properties of an object, and decide what to return or to do.

In the example below, we create a Proxy for an array. As you see in the handler, we define a `get` function. This function will be called whenever the value of a property of the target object is accessed. This includes accessing indexes or methods, as calling a method is basically retrieving the value of a property (the function) and then calling it.

As you see, if the property is an integer number, we return that position in the array. If the property is 'length' then we return the length of the array. In any other case, we return a void function.

The advantage of this is that the proxyArray still behaves like an array. You can use square brackets to get to its indexes and use the property length. But if you try to do something like `proxyArray.push(23)` nothing happens.

Of course, in a final solution, you might want decide what to do based on which 
 method is being called. You might want methods like `map`, `filter` and so on to work.

And finally, the last advantage of this approach is that you keep a reference to the original array, so you can still modify it and its values are accessible through the proxy.

```js
var handler = {
    get: function(target, property, receiver) {
      var regexp = /[\d]+/;
      if (regexp.exec(property)) { // indexes:
        return target[property];
      }
      
      if (property === 'length') {
        return target.length;
      }
      
      if (typeof (target[property]) === 'function') {
        // return a function that does nothing:
        return function() {};
      }
    }
};

// this is the original array that we keep private
var array = [1, 2, 3];

// this is the 'visible' array:
var proxyArray = new Proxy(array, handler);

console.log(proxyArray[1]);
console.log(proxyArray.length);


console.log(proxyArray.push(32)); // does nothing
console.log(proxyArray[3]); // undefined


// but if we modify the old array:
array.push(23);
console.log(array);

// the proxy is modified
console.log(proxyArray[3]); // 32
```

Of course, the poblem is that `proxyArray` is not really an array, so, depending on how you plan to use it, this might be a problem.

Comment: The issue is, I want this array to be mutated within the class but not from outside. So will this be done using `ReadOnlyArray`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't really doable in JavaScript, as far as I'm aware. The best you can hope for is to hide the data from the user as best you can. The best way to do that would be with a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

```
let privateData = new WeakMap();

class MyClass {

    constructor() {

        privateData.set(this, {
            data: []
        });

    }

    addEntry(entry) {
        privateData.get(this).data.push(entry);
    }

    getData() {
        return privateData.get(this).data.concat();
    }

}
```

So long as you never export `privateData` don't `export` from the module, or wrap within an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) etc.) then your `MyClass` instances will be able to access the data but external forces can't (other than through methods you create)

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.getData(); // -> []
myInstance.getData().push(1);
myInstance.getData(); // -> []
myInstance.addEntry(100);
myInstance.getData(); // -> [100]
```

Comment: So essentially, `data.concat();` will create a new array on `getData` which I have already done. If I'm missing something, please accept my apologies and highlight it, if possible.

Comment: Yes. Because JavaScript objects are passed by reference, if you just return `data` then any modifications made to the returned array will also affect the class' property. The main difference between my approach and your approach is that there is no `data` property on `MyClass` or `myInstance`

Comment: Sorry but I guess this makes your answer more of an optimization. I'll try to utilize this in future.